# ruby on rails: intentionally slow down pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rendering, response-time

In the site I'm building, complex pages take > 1s to load up in browser.
Simple ones take less than a second.

How can I tell rails to sleep ( 1.second - processing_time() )
before rendering any page.

The idea is to give the users a consistent waiting time.
(No page should arrive in browser in less than 1 second)

Is there a gem that can help me with this? (I'm on rails 4)

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine you can do something like this:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController

  def show
    sleep 1
    # Do something
  end
end
```

Read more about Ruby's sleep here: http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/sleep

If you are doing this all over your rails application, I would put it into your application controller and reuse it. For example:

```
class ApplicationController
  ...

  def sleep_one_second
    sleep 1
  end
end
```

In your controller, choose which actions to delay:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController

  before_action :sleep_one_second, only: [:show, :index]

  ...
end
```